# Typescript imported objects are undefined

Tags: typescript, import

I have a file called `mock_event` which is used to create an event object to be used in unit testing. You can see it being created below:

**mock_event.ts**

```
import {Event} from "../../../models/src/event";
import {EventUserView} from "../../../models/src/event_user_view";


let validEvent: Event;
validEvent = new Event({
    'eventId': '123',
    'organizer': new EventUserView({
        'displayName': 'Jim'
    })
});

export {validEvent};
```

Now, when I import the object `validEvent`, it is `undefined`. I'm pretty new to typescript, I'm sure I'm missing something, but this doesn't seem complicated. It's even undefined if I put a breakpoint on the export statement, which is pretty weird, because the object is instantiated on the line immediately prior. I don't get any exceptions. Does anyone know what is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you expected `export {validEvent};` to do, but that's probably not what you want.

You either want a default export of an object with the `validEvent` on it:

```
export default { validEvent }

// then to import:
import MockEvent from './mock_event'
MockEvent.validEvent
```

Or you want a named export:

```
export let validEvent: Event;
validEvent = new Event({
    'eventId': '123',
    'organizer': new EventUserView({
        'displayName': 'Jim'
    })
});

// Then to import
import { validEvent } from './mock_event'
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I modified the code to match your named export example, but the object is still `undefined` when imported.

Comment: Are you sure that `new Event()` returns a value then? Some constructors can fail by returning `null` or `undefined`.